# Sharepoint 2010 Approval workflow conditions

Tags: 2010, workflow, approval-process

Using SharePoint designer, how do I route the approval email based on that category? I can not seem to figure out how to send the email address, as a variable, to the approver's email parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an approver column?  Or do you have a column where approver is determined?  I am not sure what you mean by "on that category."  Please clarify so someone can help answer your question.